# Automatically sort data based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to make my spreadsheet AUTOMATICALLY sort the data based on DATE. I've attached a photo of the spreadsheet i am using.

You'll notice there is a WORKDAY formula in column G. At the moment, once i've updated the Dispensed Date, the Re-order Date updates according to the formula (based on Working Day arranged).  I then use SORT RANGE A-Z for column G to give me earliest date first. I would desperately like to automate this bit - the SORTING RANGE bit - so that once i've updated Date Dispensed, the Re-Order Date is updated according to the formula and then automatically drops the entire row to the bottom of the list.

Where I am at the moment:

Using YouTube, I've managed to make the column Auto Sort but ONLY if I change the Re-Order date myself. It is not accepting sorting the date if i update Date Dispensed. Although it does update the Re-order date to the new date, however, it does not sort the data A-Z. It stays where it is. I hope I'm making some sense.
This is the code/formula I've used based on YouTube:

```
function autoSort(e) {
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const column = e.range.getColumn();
  const ss = e.source;
  const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName();

  if (!(currentSheetName === 'ORDERPAD' && column === 7 && row >= 2)) return;

  const range = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 7);

  range.sort({ column: 7, ascending: true });
}

function onEdit(e) {
  autoSort(e);
}
```

Comment: I believe your problem is you are editing column 6 not 7.  The formula is in column 7 but if its value changes it does not trigger onEdit(e).

Comment: The question is a copy of [automatically sort data in google sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172056/269219). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getSheetName() == 'ORDERPAD' && e.range.columnStart > 5 && e.range.columnStart < 8 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, 7).sort({column:7,ascending:true});
  }
}
```